# Getting list of table comments in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql allows adding comments to objects such as tables. For example I've added a comment to table "mytable" by using this SQL command:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS 'This is my table.';
```

My question is:
If I want to use a SQL-command to get all tables along with their respective comment - how would I do this? What would be the appropriate query for this?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: \d+ myta* will give you that info (* is a wildcard)! Look [here](http://merlinmoncure.blogspot.ie/2007/10/better-psql-with-less.html) for a better pager and if  you run psql -E <your_schema>, every one of those commands issued will automacially print the SQL associated with it!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

All comments are stored in [pg_description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-description.html)

To get the comments on a table, you need to join it to [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

As an alternative you can also use the function `obj_description()` to retrieve this information:

```
SELECT obj_description(oid)
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'r'
```

**Edit**

In psql you can simply use the `\d+` command to show all tables including their comments. Or use the `\dd` command to show all comments in the system

Comment: The table name is public.mytable and ?? where it? How to query (with SELECT) a table comment?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: use: `select obj_description('public.mytable'::regclass)`

Comment: I found that `\d+` did *not* show the table comment (it shows column comments) but `\dt+` does show table comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, first at all thanks for sharing the answer!. I notice that Andrew answer is right for my case, using  PostgreSQL 9.4.4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, first at all thanks for sharing the answer!. I notice that Andrew answer is right for my case, using  PostgreSQL 9.4.4

Answer (score 21):

The main problem with "show comments" is to remember the name of specific fucntions, catalog names, etc. to retrieve the comment... Or its pages on the Guide. At this answer we solve in 2 ways: 
by a summary of the ordinary way (the pg-way) to show comments; 
and by offering shortcut functions, to reduce the "remember problem".

---

### The pg-way

The **simplest**, on `psql`, is to use `\dt+` to show table comments and `\d+` to show column comments. Some for function comments?

To get on SQL, and for people that remember all parameters, the pg-way is to use the `obj_description()` function ([Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE)) in conjunction with adequate *reg*-type:

- **Function**: `select obj_description('mySchema.myFunction'::regproc, 'pg_proc')`
- **Table or View**: 
  ("... and most everything else that has columns or is otherwise similar to a table",[guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html))
   `select obj_description('mySchema.myClass'::regclass, 'pg_class')`
- **other** generic: `select obj_description('mySchema.myObject'::regName, pg_regName)`, where `regName` is 1 in 10 of [datatype-oid references Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), and *pg_regName* is the same replacing prefix `reg` by prefix `pg_`.
- **other** specific: similar `select obj_description('schema.myObject'::regName, catalog_name)`, where *catalog_name* is to be more specific about a (1 in 95) key-word at [catalogs Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). It can reduce some "namespace pollution". For example `pg_proc` for functions, `pg_aggregate` for aggregate functions.
- to get comment for a **shared database object**, analog but using the function `shobj_description()` (same [page Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html)).
- **Column**: `select col_description('mySchema.myObject'::regClass, column_number)`, where *column_number* is the column's ordinal position (at the CREATE TABLE).
   No  column-name... See `col_description(table,column_name)` complement bellow.

IMPORTANT: the use of same *reg*-type and _catalog_name_ (e. g.  `::regclass` and `pg_class`) seems redundant and sometimes `obj_description('obj'::regObj)`  works fine, with only *reg*-type! ...But, as the Guide say:

> it is deprecated since there is no guarantee that OIDs are unique across different system catalogs; therefore, the wrong comment might be returned.

### Shortcut functions to get comments

if you are finding it difficult to remember all the type-casts and parameters, the best is to adopt  a new and simplest function to retrieve comments.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION rel_description(
     p_relname text, p_schemaname text DEFAULT NULL
 ) RETURNS text AS $f$
    SELECT obj_description((CASE 
       WHEN strpos($1, '.')>0 THEN $1
       WHEN $2 IS NULL THEN 'public.'||$1
       ELSE $2||'.'||$1
            END)::regclass, 'pg_class');
 $f$ LANGUAGE SQL;
 -- EXAMPLES OF USE:
 -- SELECT rel_description('mytable'); 
 -- SELECT rel_description('public.mytable'); 
 -- SELECT rel_description('otherschema.mytable'); 
 -- SELECT rel_description('mytable', 'otherschema'); 
 -- PS: rel_description('public.mytable', 'otherschema') is a syntax error, 
 --     but not generates exception: returns the same as ('public.mytable')
```

We need also something less ugly to show column comments.  There are no kind of `pg_get_serial_sequence()` function to get ordinal position of a **column** from its name. The native 
`col_description('mySchema.myObject'::regClass, column_number)`
 needs a  complement:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION col_description(
    p_relname text,  -- table name or schema.table 
    p_colname text,   -- table's column name
    p_database text DEFAULT NULL -- NULL for current
 ) RETURNS text AS $f$
    WITH r AS (
      SELECT CASE WHEN array_length(x,1)=1 THEN array['public',x[1]] ELSE x END
      FROM regexp_split_to_array(p_relname,'\.') t(x)
     ) 
    SELECT col_description(p_relname::regClass, ordinal_position)
    FROM r, information_schema.columns i
    WHERE i.table_catalog = CASE 
        WHEN $3 IS NULL THEN current_database() ELSE $3 
      END and i.table_schema  = r.x[1]
      and i.table_name    = r.x[2]
      and i.column_name = p_colname
 $f$ LANGUAGE SQL;
 -- SELECT col_description('tableName','colName'); 
 -- SELECT col_description('schemaName.tableName','colName','databaseName);
```

---

NOTES:

- As recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343177/287948): "*If you want to know which queries does psql run when you do \dt+ or \d+ customers, just launche it with `psql -E`*".
- It is possible to express multiline comment, using any [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457183/287948) (with E`\n` or `$$...$$`)... 
  But you can't apply `trim()` or use another dynamic aspect. Must use [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721603/287948) on [COMMENT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) clause for it.
- No comments to see? PostgreSQL programmers not use [COMMENT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) clause  because it is **ugly to use**: there are no syntax to add comment on CREATE TABLE or on [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html); and there are no good IDE to automatize it.
- The modern http://postgREST.org/ interface show comments on the Web!

Comment: Why don't you simply use: `select obj_description('public.mytable'::regclass, 'pg_class')` (or use a SQL client that just displays that information)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name. About the direct use of `obj_description()`, see the section "The pg-way":  it  is not simple to retrieve a column comment, a function comment, etc. It is ugly to remember all stuff... and there  are other problems and shortcuts.  Now the answer **is a Wiki**, you and  **any reader** (!) can edit it and enhance the answer.

Comment: DataGrip from JetBrains supports comments just fine.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `pg_catalog.obj_description` function and `information_schema.tables` schema view:

```
SELECT t.table_name, pg_catalog.obj_description(pgc.oid, 'pg_class')
FROM information_schema.tables t
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class pgc
ON t.table_name = pgc.relname 
WHERE t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
AND t.table_schema='public';
```

[FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE)

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA Support in MySQL, PostgreSQL](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/666.cfm)

Comment: Does not work when multiple schemas have the same table name.

Answer (score 4):

If you still have tables with mixed case names you can use the following to get a complete list of all tables in a database with their comment, as well as catalog, schema, table type, etc. (tested in PostGIS - pgAdmin 4):

```
select *,
    obj_description((table_schema||'.'||quote_ident(table_name))::regclass)
from information_schema.tables where table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
```

Comment: I like this one since it works with multiple schemas and avoids all the joins required to work with multiple schemas.