# Defining multi-line strings in psql

Tags: postgresql, console, psql

I would like to paste

```
  123
  456
  789
```

into `psql` and to store multi-line string in some variable (ie. `:str`) for later use.

Is that possible? Now I'm getting `unterminated quoted string` error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A little clunky, but you can do it with [\gset](http://www.depesz.com/2013/02/03/waiting-for-9-3-create-a-psql-command-gset-to-store-query-results-into-psql-variables/) in conjunction with a [dollar-quoted literal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING):

```
SELECT
$$123
456
789$$ AS str \gset
```