# SQL access comments in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, comments

I have been trying to find a ***SQL*** approach to retrieve [comments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) of my **schemas** and other database objects in PostgreSQL.

I have seen the following questions in stack**overflow**:
[How to retrieve the comment of a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493978/how-to-retrieve-the-comment-of-a-postgresql-database) which shows how to fetch comments for databases, with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_shdescription JOIN pg_database ON objoid =
pg_database.oid;
```

[Getting list of table comments in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664094/getting-list-of-table-comments-in-postgresql)
which shows how to get comments for tables, the command is `SELECT obj_description('myschema.mytable'::regclass);` for a specific table in a schema.

[Retrieving Comments from a PostgreSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343138/retrieving-comments-from-a-postgresql-db) which shows how to fetch the comments for all the columns in the database, the command is :

```
SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name,pgd.description
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables AS st
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description pgd ON (pgd.objoid=st.relid)
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c ON (pgd.objsubid=c.ordinal_position
AND c.table_schema=st.schemaname AND c.table_name=st.relname);
```

These assess the question of fetching comments from a database, tables and columns, but they do not give the answer for other database objects such as schemas.

I have taken a look at [obj_description(object_oid, catalog_name)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE) but did not manage to make it work... for schemas, views, etc.

(I am mainly interested in schemas, but since there are other situations that might interest other developers, I would like to have all the solutions in one place).

Any clues?

> EDIT: [found](http://golden13.blogspot.fi/2012/08/how-to-get-some-information-about_7.html) a way to get the comments from **schemas**... Seems a bit
>   complicated, could be simplier.
>   Here is the code:

```
SELECT

CASE 
    WHEN nspname LIKE E'pg\_temp\_%' THEN 1 
    WHEN (nspname LIKE E'pg\_%') THEN 0  
    ELSE 3 
END AS nsptyp, nsp.nspname, nsp.oid, pg_get_userbyid(nspowner) 
    AS namespaceowner, 
    nspacl, description,  
    has_schema_privilege(nsp.oid, 'CREATE') as cancreate 
FROM pg_namespace nsp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_description des ON des.objoid=nsp.oid  
WHERE NOT ((nspname = 'pg_catalog' AND EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM pg_class 
    WHERE relname = 'pg_class' 
    AND relnamespace = nsp.oid LIMIT 1)) OR  
(nspname = 'information_schema' AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class 
            WHERE relname = 'tables' 
            AND relnamespace = nsp.oid LIMIT 1)) OR  
(nspname LIKE '_%' AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_proc 
            WHERE proname='slonyversion' 
            AND pronamespace = nsp.oid LIMIT 1)) OR  
(nspname = 'dbo' AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class 
            WHERE relname = 'systables' 
            AND relnamespace = nsp.oid LIMIT 1)) OR  
(nspname = 'sys' AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class 
            WHERE relname = 'all_tables' 
            AND relnamespace = nsp.oid LIMIT 1))
) 
AND nspname NOT LIKE E'pg\_temp\_%'
AND nspname NOT LIKE E'pg\_toast_temp\_%' 
ORDER BY 1, nspname
```

As the original code is quite lengthy and I like concise solutions, here is something better:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_namespace AS nsp LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_description AS des ON des.objoid=nsp.oid;
```

The long code basically excludes a bunch of schemas from PostgreSQL (though I do not know why it doesn't hide pg_toast on my machine).

Comment: I wonder why something like COMMENT isn't/wasn't part of the SQL standard, or why there is a command to add a comment but not retrieve them? Seems really useful to have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of research, I have come to the conclusion that one can use the following code to get descriptions of objects in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM [pg_catalog_table] AS nsp LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_description AS des ON des.objoid=nsp.oid;
```

The [pg_catalog_table] should be substituted by a table in the pg_catalog which contains an OID column... For instance (but not limited):
pg_type ; pg_namespace ; etc.

And use this code

```
SELECT * FROM pg_database AS nsp  LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_shdescription AS sdes ON sdes.objoid=nsp.oid;
```

for descriptions from databases.

For views is a bit more tricky as they are listed in pg_class which also lists the rest of the objects (more work to do here).

There doesn't seem to be comments for servers.