# How to get the OID of a Postgres table?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, objectid, zend-db-table

Does anyone know how to find the OID of a table in Postgres 9.1?

I am writing an update script that needs to test for the existence of a column in a table before it tries to add the column. This is to prevent errors when running the script repeatedly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The postgres catalog table `pg_class` is what you should look at. There should be one row per table, with the table name in the column `relname`, and the oid in the hidden column `oid`.

You may also be interested in the `pg_attribute` catalog table, which includes one row per table column.

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html

Comment: I had seen the docs on the `pg_class` and `pg_attribute` tables, but I didn't know that there was a hidden column named `oid` in the `pg_class` table.  I couldn't figure out where the oid was from the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not quite accurate. Every database has a schema named `pg_catalog`, which contains catalog tables specific to the database.

Comment: I second @TonyVitabile. It was the hidden column `oid` that I was looking for.

Comment: Removed incorrect information regarding the database to connect to. Just noting since @JakobEgger's comment will now seem out of place.

Answer (score 80):

To get a table OID, cast to the [object identifier type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) `regclass` (while connected to the same DB!). This finds the first table (or view etc.) with the given (unqualified) name along the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) or raises an exception if not found:

```
SELECT 'mytbl'::regclass::oid;
```

Schema-qualify the table name to remove the dependency on the search path:

```
SELECT 'myschema.mytbl'::regclass::oid;
```

Since Postgres **9.4** we can also use `to_regclass()`, which returns `null` instead of raising an exception if the table is not found:

```
SELECT to_regclass('myschema.mytbl');
```

See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Then query the catalog table [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) for the existence of a given column:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_attribute 
   WHERE  attrelid = 'myschema.mytbl'::regclass
   AND    attname  = 'mycol'
   AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
   -- AND    attnum > 0     -- no system columns - you may or may not want this
   );
;
```

This way you get:

- an error if no table (or view etc.) of that name exists
- `false` if the column does not exist
- `true` if the column exists (incl. system columns)

Comment: Just want to point out how this answer from 2012 is bang on. Just, you know, you made my life easier, today, @erin-brandstetter! Ya' did well, and much thanks.

Comment: @Sam: Good to hear! I did keep it up to date (like just now again). `to_regclass()` didn't even exist, yet, in 2012.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl_name' AND relkind = 'r';
```

Comment: @eirikir Postgres stores information about every table created by user as well as about system tables in the system catalog (actually table) pg_class, so you can get oid using this query.

It is funny, but information about pg_class is also stored in pg_class:

postgres=# SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'pg_class';
 oid  | relname  
------+----------
 1259 | pg_class
(1 row)

Comment: @ololobus No, I believe the comment by eirikir was not a request for further info but a criticism to the author of this Answer. The creators of Stack Overflow intended for this site to be more than a code snippet library. So, Answers are expected to have some explanation along with any example code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the possibilities I'd like to add that there exists a syntax for dropping columns in order to no error out:

ALTER TABLE mytbl
  DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS mycol

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-altertable.html

Then you can safely add your column.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Now, you can get the OID of `person` table with `regclass` type or `to_regclass()` and `oid` type as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 'public.person'::regclass::oid;
  oid
-------
 26880
(1 row)
```

Or:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT to_regclass('public.person')::oid;
 to_regclass
-------------
       26880
(1 row)
```

Or:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT CAST(CAST('public.person' AS regclass) AS oid);
  oid
-------
 26880
(1 row)
```

Or:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT CAST(to_regclass('public.person') AS oid);
 to_regclass
-------------
       26880
(1 row)
```

*Memos:

- You must do type conversion with `::` or `CAST()` to get the OID of `person` table. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809547/convert-integer-to-string-in-postgresql#77723276) explains how to do type conversion.
- You can omit the schema `public.`.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) explains `to_regclass()` in detail.

In addition, not using `oid` type cannot get the OID of `person` table as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 'public.person'::regclass::oid;
 regclass
----------
 person
(1 row)
```

And, there is some case which you can omit `oid` type as shown below. *Setting `oid` type for the example below gets the same results:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT relhastriggers FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'public.person'::regclass;
 relhastriggers
----------------
 f
(1 row)
```

And, you can still get the OID of `person` table from [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) without `regclass` type or `to_regclass()` and `oid` type as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'person';
  oid
-------
 26880
(1 row)
```

Lastly, you create `my_v` view as shown below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT * FROM person;
```

Then, you can get the OID of `my_v` view with `regclass` type or `to_regclass()` and `oid` type as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT 'public.my_v'::regclass::oid;
  oid
-------
 16421
(1 row)
```

Or:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT to_regclass('public.my_v')::oid;
 to_regclass
-------------
       16421
(1 row)
```