# Get column names which do not match a particular ending string

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
abc_col | abcd | ab_col 
        |      |
        |      |
```

Some column names end in `_col` and some do not. `abc` or `ab` or `abcd` are random column name beginnings. I want to select the names of columns which do not end in `_col`.

The function `RIGHT()` can do this but due to some extended constraints I cannot use `RIGHT()`. I want to form an SQL statement which does not involve any standard function of SQL for this problem.

By "standard functions" I mean functions like `RIGHT()`, `LEFT()` and so on. `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE` are fine.

Comment: Are you talking about column *names* or *values*. You write about column names like those were values. Provide example code (even if it isn't working) and, as *always*, your version of Postgres. Also, define "standard function of SQL".

Comment: I am talking about column names and not values. By standard function I meant that I do not want to use any function like `RIGHT()` or `LFET()` to do the job.

Comment: So, `NOT LIKE` qualifies as not one of those functions?

Comment: No NOT LIKE does not qualifies. I am trying NOT LIKE to see if everything runs correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve column names from the system catalogs or the [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html). Using the system catalog table [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html):

```
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_attribute 
WHERE  attrelid = 'mytbl'::regclass
AND    attname NOT LIKE '%_col'
AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    attnum > 0;       -- no system columns
```

More information in this related answer:

- [Determining the OID of a table in Postgres 9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953123/determining-the-oid-of-a-table-in-postgres-9-1/10956124#10956124)

Answer (score 0):

You should find information_schema

```
SELECT table_name, 
       column_name, 
       REPLACE(column_name, '_1', '') 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%_col' 
       AND table_name = 'matches' 
       AND table_schema = 'public';
```