# Entity framework materialized view not showing in wizard

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, materialized-views

I am using PostgreSQL 12 with EF6. I am trying to add materialized view to my model but the view is not listed in the model wizard. I know to be able to add a view into a model, Entity Framework needs at least one column in database view to be not nullable. But I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried creating unique index and also rownumber with no success.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "Stock"
AS

SELECT coalesce(cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as int), 0) as "Id",
    "PartMaster"."PartID",
    "OEMPart"."PartCatalogID",
    "PartMaster"."PartCode",
    "PartCatalog"."CustomPartCode",
    "OEMPart"."OEMCode",
    "PartMaster"."PartDesc",
    "GoodsReceivedDetail"."Cost",
    "GoodsReceivedDetail"."Markup",
    "GoodsReceivedDetail"."SellingPrice",
    coalesce("GoodsReceivedDetail"."Quantity", 0) as "InQuantity",
    coalesce("InvoiceDetail"."Quantity", 0) as "OutQuantity", 
    coalesce("GoodsReceivedDetail"."Quantity", 0) - coalesce("InvoiceDetail"."Quantity", 0) as "StockQuantity"
FROM
    "PartCatalog"
INNER JOIN
    "PartMaster"
ON
    (
        "PartCatalog"."PartID" = "PartMaster"."PartID")
INNER JOIN
    "OEMPart"
ON
    (
        "PartCatalog"."PartID" = "OEMPart"."PartID")
INNER JOIN
    "GoodsReceivedDetail"
ON
    (
        "OEMPart"."PartCatalogID" = "GoodsReceivedDetail"."PartCatalogID")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "InvoiceDetail"
ON
    (
        "GoodsReceivedDetail"."PartCatalogID" = "InvoiceDetail"."PartCatalogID")
INNER JOIN
    "PartCategory"
ON
    (
        "PartMaster"."PartCategoryID" = "PartCategory"."PartCategoryID") ;
        
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Id"
  ON "Stock" ("PartCatalogID");
```

Comment: Is your question how to make sure one of the columns in your Materialized View is not nullable? If so, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242219/how-to-indicate-that-a-column-is-not-nullable-when-creating-a-materialized-view/47245081#47245081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this object visible, simply add a view to your database.

```
CREATE VIEW stock_view
AS select * from Stock
```

Note: Materialized views are used to increase query performance. If you do not have performance issues, stick to regular views. Simply re-write your original materialized view as a regular view by removing the word `materialized`.

To answer your original question on how to make column `Id` in table `Stock` not nullable, you can combine the answers in
[this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242219/how-to-indicate-that-a-column-is-not-nullable-when-creating-a-materialized-view/47245081#47245081) with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953123/determining-the-oid-of-a-table-in-postgres-9-1#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20table%20OID,an%20exception%20if%20not%20found.) as follows:

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_attribute 
SET attnotnull = true
WHERE attrelid = Stock::regclass::oid
 and attname  = 'Id'
```

Comment: Thanks Lars for the suggestion. I have already tried the given solution(altering the table), but the wizard still doesn't shows views.

Comment: I see. Are you sure you’re looking at the right schema? Your stock view is created without specifying one, so it’s going to be in a default one.

Comment: I updated my question with instructions on how to create a view on top of your structure, which begs the question why you need a materialized view. They should be used for performance. If you don't have query performance issues, simply use a view instead.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Normal view is visible in the wizard. But if you find a solution for materialized view, please update the question.