# SQL/Java concurrent transaction deadlock

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, transactions, deadlock

I have a method `boolean addIntegerColumnToDatabases(String tableName, String columnName, Connection ... conns)` where I have a collection of SQL-Connections.

For every SQL-Connection I execute the schema-update-query

```sql
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE <b>tableName</b> ADD COLUMN <b>columnName</b> int4
COMMIT
```

Since this method must be ACID I like to do this in parallel.

In example I have two connections (C1, C2):

> C1: BEGIN
>
> C2: BEGIN
>
> C1: ALTER TABLE **tableName** ADD COLUMN **columnName** int4
>
> C2: ALTER TABLE **tableName** ADD COLUMN **columnName** int4
>
> C1: COMMIT
>
> C2: COMMIT

This is the code:

```
Statement[] s = new Statement[conns.length];
int i =0;
for(Connection c:conns) {
  c.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  s[i++]=c.createStatement();
}
for(Statement st:s) {
  st.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE "+tableName+" ADD COLUMN "+columnName+" int4;");
}
for(Connection c:conns) {
  c.commit();
}
return true;
```

This works as long as the connections are on different databases.

### Problem

If C1 and C2 are connected to the same database C2 waits for the C1 to be committed on Postgres-Side and C1 waits for C2 on Java-Side. Voila we have a deadlock.

I have no 100% chance to check if the connections are to the same database system because of issues like clustering/balancing, ipv4/6 and dns-issues.

### Question

How to make sure to `return false;` if execution having two connections to the same database without executing any schema-change?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `c.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);` is useless in Postgres because it does not support dirty reads.

Comment: Are you aware that schema migration tools like Liquibase have already solved this problem? (and many more as well)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I dont like liquibase, its architecture is dirty.

Comment: It has been working just fine for me for over 10 years in about 20 projects.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am sure it also works well for more that 10 years in more than 20 projects for many more people. Doesnt change the fact that its architecture is dirty. I mean who actually does the version controll? Who is the authority of concurrent version control (git, svn, cvs) or the changelog-xmls or the database or all of them? Who wins in a case of difference, the database or the changelog?

Comment: The architecture is most definitely not dirty. The "authority" is the same version control where your application code is stored, because that's where the migrations (XML, SQL) are stored.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Keep in mind that changelog can remove columns that have been created by previous changelogs. So setting up a new database will add a column and remove it some changelogs later. But I checked out a specific version of the project what have added some Java-classes in the past and removed those classes again what is not part of the current checkout-version of the project. So why must the database do this but the vcs not? You have the whole database history checked out. You must have redundant db-informations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a help table `database_instance` filled with a GUID.

Before the schema-update-query, get the GUID and lock it in a local dictionary.

Or simply lock the table locally, no matter which database it is located on:

```sql
var tablename = new object();
lock(tablename)
{
   <your query>
}
```

Comment: Good idea. For my approach unfortunately useless because I am not sure that this table exists. If the table does not exists I must create it and violate this way against the `without executing any schema-change`-requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) for that.

An advisory lock uses an arbitrary number provided by the caller and exists until it's explicitly released or the connection is closed. You can [convert the tablename to its oid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10956124) and use that number as the lock identifier.

Something like (without error handling or cleanup!)

```
ResultSet st.executeQuery("select pg_try_advisory_lock('" + tableName + "'::regclass::oid::bigint)");
rs.next();
boolean locked = rs.getBoolean(1);
if (locked) {
  // do your migration
  .....

  // once you are done with the table, release the lock immediately
  // alternatively keep it open and it will be released automatically 
  // when the connection is closed
  st.execute("select pg_advisory_unlock('" + tableName + "'::regclass::oid::bigint)");
} else {
  // handle the conflict
}
```

Maybe you want to move that functionality into it's own method.

---

Alternatively you could just try to acquire one lock with some hard-coded number at the start of the migration (independently of the table to be modified).

Comment: This is a good idea, but even if the question is related to postgres it must work in other database systems, even exotic ones and system in the future. And I try to use methods that are normal SQL standard.

Comment: You are experienced, could you please check my latest suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterRader: so how will you handle databases that don't support transaction DDL?

Comment: Well they need to handle transaction. Thats is another restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I have another idea.

I could first measure what time consumptation will be expected for every single database by simply executing `ROLLBACK` instead of `COMMIT`.

Lets say

1. is a single time consumptation between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` of one database 
   and
2. is the amount of all time-consumptations.
3. is the maximum, the hightest value of all measured time consumptations  **max()**.

Then I will set the Watchdog timeout to

```
2 *
```

If the watchdog balks we have duplicate databaseconnections and clearly must return `false`.