# Using PostgreSQL comments as descriptions in dbt docs

Tags: postgresql, dbt, code-documentation, psqlodbc

We've been adding comments to the columns in postgres as column descriptions. Similarly, there are descriptions in dbt that can be written.

How would I go about writing SQL to automatically setting the same descriptions in postgres into dbt docs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I often do it.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4946306/3907405) on how to pull descriptions from the pg.catalog.

From there, you want to write a BQ query that generates a json which you can then convert to a yaml file you can use directly in dbt.

[BQ link](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=162045639883:6338c6ca4c81493ab2c614b405ff669a) - save results as JSON file.

Use a [json2yaml](https://gist.github.com/noahcoad/46909253a5891af3699580b8f17baba8) tool.

Save yaml file to an appropriate place in your project tree.

Code sample:

```
-- intended to be saved as JSON and converted to YAML
-- ex. cat script_job_id_1.json | python3 json2yaml.py | tee schema.yml 
-- version will be created as version:'2' . Remove quotes after conversion

DECLARE database STRING;
DECLARE dataset STRING;
DECLARE dataset_desc STRING;
DECLARE source_qry STRING;


SET database = "bigquery-public-data";
SET dataset = "census_bureau_acs";
SET dataset_desc = "";
SET source_qry = CONCAT('''CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE tt_master_table AS ''',
                    '''(''',
                    '''SELECT cfp.table_name, ''',
                        '''cfp.column_name, ''',
                        '''cfp.description, ''',
                        '''FROM `''', database, '''`.''', dataset, '''.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS cfp ''',
                    ''')''');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE source_qry;

WITH column_info AS (

  SELECT table_name as name,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column_name AS name, COALESCE(description,"") AS description)) AS columns
  FROM tt_master_table
  GROUP by table_name

)

, table_level AS (
SELECT CONCAT(database, ".", dataset) AS name, 
database,
dataset,
dataset_desc AS `description`,
ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(name, columns)) AS tables
FROM column_info
GROUP BY database,
dataset,
dataset_desc
LIMIT 1)

SELECT CAST(2 AS INT) AS version,
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, database, dataset, description, tables)) AS sources
FROM table_level
GROUP BY version
```

Comment: So you have an airflow (or similar) job that runs that takes the query, exports it to json, converts it to a yaml, and then overwrite it in the correct place in the dbt dir?

Comment: No, we haven't needed to automate it (yet). Right now we just step through the above manually. But there are of course loads of ways it could be scripted. You could probably even pull it off with hooks when the new Python models functionality goes live. https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/5261